# How to set Background of an Class Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image

I don't have any XML-Layout's. I directly start my Activity like that

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(new DrawingPanel(this));
```

It's a drawing App and the default Background is Black. I want to change the Background to an ImageBackground. How can I do that?

EDIT: IT'S NOT ABOUT JUST SETTING A BACKGROUND. I´ve got a SurfaceView (DrawingPanel) with a black Background by default. I want to change the black background to a Picture, so I can draw ON the picture.

Comment: try `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(resourceId);`

Comment: didn't work. image is not visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mypicture);
scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
```

and then using

```
canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
```

solved that problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
        parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // here set your background
        parent.addView(new DrawingPanel(this));
        setContentView(parent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I support @haresh, I think the problem occur because you are trying to load big images. Here is a good tutorial how to load large bitmaps.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: i tried it with setting just a color with 'setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)' , didn't work also. don't think it has to do with the size images.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine to set the background image.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     setContentView(imageView);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me

```
            logo = new ImageView(this);
    logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync_cloud_logo);
    logo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.drawer_bkground));// your color
            setContentView(logo);
```